# ¿Como consulto la información de una tabla de MYSQL cuando queiro que se cumpland dos conidiciones?

Tags: php, mysql

he intentado hacer un select para mostrar la información de cada fila desde la BD pero siempre que consulto el 2 registro me trae la información del primero.

```
$artsql ="SELECT Id_Noti,Titulo, Titulo_Sec, Descripcion,nombre, ruta
FROM tbl_contenido WHERE id = id AND Id_Noti= Id_Noti";

$res = $objConexion->query($artsql) or die($objConexion->error);

$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por Ejemplo consulto la información de segundo registros que dice Título Principal y me muestra la Información del primero donde esta el Nombre de David Herrera

Esto se consulta al dar clic en el icono de editar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el query no esta bien no? quisiste pasarle variables que no le agregaste al query? asi como esta, el where iguala los campos a si mismos, con lo cual no hace nada...

Comment: Haz consultado que las variables del `WHERE` sean las correspondientes al `ID` del segundo registro?

Comment: En el `WHERE` de tu consulta: `WHERE id = id AND Id_Noti= Id_Noti` **a la derecha de los signos de igualdad debe ir un valor**, por ejemplo: si pones `WHERE id = 6 AND Id_Noti= 2` debería traerte los datos de `Título Principal`

Comment: ¿estas enviando los parámetros para modificar la consulta al dar clic en editar? de ser así ¿cómo los estas envíando?

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un WHERE en la consulta de MySQL para que obtengas lo requerido, entiendo que quieres que solo se muestre la informacion de "David Herrera" por ejmeplo, arma la Query asi con la varible correpondiente

```
SELECT Id_Noti,Titulo, Titulo_Sec, Descripcion,nombre, ruta
FROM tbl_contenido WHERE id = "VARIABLE" AND Id_Noti= "VARIABLE"
```

Comment: El where lo tiene.. lo que no esta pasando son variables al query...

Comment: Pero agrega la variable en el cod PHP para que lo ejecute en MySQL

Comment: Si muchas gracias, si me faltaba la variable para que me mostrara los datos correspondientes